# Package a Google Doc Add-on for publishing

Tags: google-apps-script, libraries, google-docs, add-on

I have an editor add-on in App script that I have developed.  Everything is in a library.  It uses a sidebar and help dialog using HTML Service. And it can edit the Doc from events on the sidebar. But two things I can't figure out.  I've looked at various pages on Add-on but can't quite figure it out.

First how to add the Add-on menus from the librar.  And second, how to handle server calls from the menu or sidebar.
I have been testing as a library resource and right now the Doc Code.gs contains 2 function.

The similar questions do not answer this directly.

```
function onOpen() {
  try {
    var cpMenu = DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();
    cpMenu.addItem("Side Bar","CalcPad.showSideBar");
    cpMenu.addItem("Calculate","CalcPad.calculate");
    cpMenu.addItem("Help","CalcPad.showHelp");
    cpMenu.addToUi();
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
};

function runCalcPadRequest(request) {
  try {
    return CalcPad.runCalcPadRequest(request);
  }
  catch(err) {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
};
```

How do I move these to the library and configure the manifest so that they are envoked.  On the sidebar there is a help button that when clicked displays the help dialog.  But this requires a server call (Doc Code.gs) as shown above.  google.script.run.CalcPad.runCalcPadRequest doesn't work.

```
function helpOnClick() {
  try {
    google.script.run.runCalcPadRequest({ name: "showHelp" });
  }
  catch(err) {
    showMessage("Error in JS_Sidebar.helpOnClick: "+err);
  }
};
```

Any advise appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: @Ruben,  your response in no way answers my question.  Can you please reopen?  I am trying to understand the proper configuration of a editor add-on that can be publish on the Google Market place.

Comment: "understand the proper configuration of a editor add-on" this is way too broad please edit the question to describe why the referred question doesn't helps or where do you get stuck. Please bear in mind that questions should be specific. Ref. [ask].

Comment: @Ruben if I install an add-on form "Get Add-on" menu item nothing is added to the Doc  Code.gs yet after installation I can pick the add-on from the Add-on menu and I can interact with the Doc.  This is the step I am struggling with.  How to have everything necessary in my library to publish as an add-on and submit for Google review to add to the Market place

Comment: Please bear in mind that it's not necessary to use a library to publish an add-on. Have you tried bt he quickstarts an samples from Google?

Comment: @Ruben "bt"?  I have tried several examples from Google Add-on pages but they all seem to be for Workgroup.  Mine is an "Editor Add-on".

Comment: @Ruben I'll give you a sneak peak.  Using plane text a user can enter an equation.  Parts can come from the side bar such as symbols.  For example a := b + c, where b = 2 and c = 3.  On the following line a =.  Click a button on the sidebar and a = 5 would be displayed.

Comment: You have looking at the wrong section. Here a link to a quickstart for an Editor add-on -> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/editors/docs/quickstart/translate. On the left panel of the linked page there are other Editor add-on quickstarts. I suggest you to study the Editor quickstarts and if you get stuck at some point post a new question.

Comment: @Ruben I have seen this example and what confuses me about this example is everything is done from a Google Doc.  onOpen, onInstall, showSideBar are all working from a single Code.gs file simply renamed.  How publishing packages all this as an add-on is unclear.  Also I have been working with a test Doc and a library.  If I simply put everything into a Doc and publish does that make it an add-on anyone can use without inserting something into the new Doc's Code.gs?

Comment: Please post a new question following the guidelines of [ask].

Comment: @Ruben I don't know how I can describe this more clearly.  My question is, I'm a first time Google Add-on developer that wants to publish my Add-on for the market place.  If I publish and its incomplete because I have not addressed UI access to my add-on and communication of my add-on with Google Doc server then it could be rejected and I still where I am today.

Comment: [Edit] relevant parts of the comments into your question. You need a "standalone" script and everything in that script acts as if it is "bound", when published. There is no need for a library.

Comment: @TheMaster, thank, I've done that.  Now I need to do the hard part, the graphic that will sell my add-on on the marketplace.